# Converting complex Powershell objects into Json with arrays of single elements

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to construct a complex powershell object containing nested hashtables and arrays, and then using the ConvertTo-Json function to convert the whole lot into Json.

I am experiencing a problem where - if an array object has only a single element, the Json that is returned is not returned as an array but as a single object.  That is to say, it is missing the enclosing square brackets in the json.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem:

```
function GetMyArrayData
{
    param($myData)

    $myArrayOfInfo = $myData  -split '\s*[,;]\s*'

    $myReturnArray = @()

    foreach($infoItem in $myArrayOfInfo)
    {
        $hashObj = @{
            field1 = "standard-value"
            field2 = $infoItem
        }

        $myReturnArray += $hashObj
    }
    return $myReturnArray
}

$myFirstArray = GetMyArrayData -myData "abc;def"

$mySecondArray = GetMyArrayData -myData "xyz"

$myBigObject = @{
    item1 = "my-first-item"
    item2 = "my-second-item"
    myArray1 = $myFirstArray
    myArray2 = $mySecondArray
}

$myJsonVersion = ConvertTo-Json $myBigObject -Depth 5

Write-Output $myJsonVersion
```

This code then outputs the following JSON:

```
{
    "item2":  "my-second-item",
    "myArray1":  [
                     {
                         "field1":  "standard-value",
                         "field2":  "abc"
                     },
                     {
                         "field1":  "standard-value",
                         "field2":  "def"
                     }
                 ],
    "myArray2":  {
                     "field1":  "standard-value",
                     "field2":  "xyz"
                 },
    "item1":  "my-first-item"
}
```

Notice that "myArray2" is converted to a single object, rather than an array containing a single object.

It *should* be rendered thus:

```
{
    "item2":  "my-second-item",
    "myArray1":  [
                     {
                         "field1":  "standard-value",
                         "field2":  "abc"
                     },
                     {
                         "field1":  "standard-value",
                         "field2":  "def"
                     }
                 ],
    "myArray2":  [
                     {
                         "field1":  "standard-value",
                         "field2":  "xyz"
                     }
                 ],
    "item1":  "my-first-item"
}
```

Can anyone advise what is wrong with this code that prevents it from outputting myArray2 as an array containing a single object?

Thanks heaps,

David :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return arrays and collections from a function PwerShell will “unroll” them. If the array contains a single object, it will return that object rather than an array.

You can work around this in a couple of ways - inside your function you can do this:

```
return @(, $myReturnArray )
```

which wraps your return value in an outer array - Powershell will then unroll *that* rather than your inner array, so your single item array is returned intact, or you can do this:

```
$myFirstArray = @( GetMyArrayData -myData "abc;def" )
```

which wraps the return value in a new array. If the return value is already an array it basically creates a shallow copy, but if it’s a single object it will be bundled onto an array.

Comment: thanks heaps - that explanation was very helpful, and wrapping the return value in an array fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the [@() array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) or the [unary comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-) to force the variable into an array:

```
myArray1 = @($myFirstArray)
myArray2 = @($mySecondArray)
```

or

```
myArray1 = ,$myFirstArray
myArray2 = ,$mySecondArray
```

Note that you still will lose the `[]` if you pipe the `$MyBigObject` through to the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet. Using `-InputObject` (as you implicitely do) is the correct way here.

Comment: thanks heaps - your explanation was also very helpful - especially the warning about piping.  Alas, I can only mark one answer as the one that solved the issue.  But it has increased my understanding of what is happening in powershell functions and arrays. So thanks heaps! :-)